# What is the correct way of doing this? I get undefined result because the variable has not been assigned a value yet

Tags: javascript, undefined

If i assign 0 to result it becomes undefined, also the return statement returns undefined as the result is not defined. How do i solve this? (I am new to JS)

```js
let numOne = prompt('Enter a number');
let numTwo = prompt('Enter another number');
let op = prompt('Wirte how you would calculate these numbers');

let result = 0;

function calc(numOne, numTwo, op, result) {
    if (op === 'add') {
        return result = (numOne + numTwo)
    } else if (op === 'minus') {
        return result = (numOne - numTwo)
    } else if (op === 'multiply') {
        return result = (numOne * numTwo)
    } else if (op === 'divide') {
        return result = (numOne / numTwo)
    } else return 'Something went wrong!'
}
answer = document.getElementById('main-p').innerHTML = (`You chose to ${op} ${numOne} and ${numTwo}.The result is ${result}!`)
```

```html
<p id="main-p"> </p>
```

Comment: You never call the function ..? Also, the variables `numOne` and `numTwo` are local to the function, they are not accessible outside of the function.

Comment: You need a total beginner's tutorial first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code like this.

Things to notice

1) Call function like `let result = calc(Number(numOne), Number(numTwo), op);`

2) Convert into numbers. As prompt will return in string you have to convert them into numbers like `calc(Number(numOne)`

3) Just return output. no need to assign it in the function

```js
let numOne = prompt('Enter a number');
let numTwo = prompt('Enter another number');
let op = prompt('Wirte how you would calculate these numbers');

let result = calc(Number(numOne), Number(numTwo), op);

function calc(numOne, numTwo, op) {
    if (op === 'add') {
        return (numOne + numTwo)
    } else if (op === 'minus') {
        return (numOne - numTwo)
    } else if (op === 'multiply') {
        return (numOne * numTwo)
    } else if (op === 'divide') {
        return (numOne / numTwo)
    } else return 'Something went wrong!'
}
answer = document.getElementById('main-p').innerHTML = (`You chose to ${op} ${numOne} and ${numTwo}.The result is ${result}!`)
```

```html
<div id='main-p'></div>
```